# Unable to add users to a sharepoint site

Tags: wss-3.0

I'm not able to add a small selection of users to a sharepoint site on Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 and when I click on address book the users aren't seen. I have tried putting in email address, alias and their surname but nothing works.

I am doing the following:
Site Actions --> Site Settings --> People and Groups --> New --> Add Users

These users are all found under email and Active Directory Users and Computers and these users were setup 10/4.

I see failure as follows:

[image: Add User failure]

Also I only see the following services on my sharepoint server:

[image: SharepointServices]

When I am logged on as serv8491 I continue to see the issue.

Does this point at Active Directory or something within Sharepoint? Is there anything I can check on the database?

Perhaps I can compare a user that is added versus these problem users.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this happening for only few users or it is happening for all the users? Please check if user profile sync is working on your environment.  also ensure that this users are not disable (accounts are valid).  do you have a screen capture of the issue

Answer (score 0):

Are all users in the same container?  As @Sudhir mentioned check their status.  WSS doesn't have a profile sync. so People picker should query directly against AD - returning all valid users.

Check the permission of the farm account.  If you logon as the farm account can access user and computers and view the accounts?  If not your default AD permissions have been altered (all domain accounts by default can see these objects). At that point you'll have to do some digging on assigned rights and check OU with users in it to see what security policy is.

Also - is there any issue with content.  If your site or DB is in read only mode or database can not grow any larger this could be contributing to this issue.

Comment: @jshelbyjr I don't know the farm account. Is there any way of checking this? I'm a domain administrator myself and another user that has full access is showing up in the same OU as the problem users. Quite a number of databases for sharepoint but they don't appear to be read only (I have also been granted full access since the issue appeared) and also lots of space.

Comment: Typically your farm account will run the SPTimerservice.  So you can bring up the service.msc console and look at that account running that.  That's usually the quickest way.

Comment: @jshelbyjr I added the services I see in the description but I have nothing like you describe. Only thing in event viewer "a new query machine has been added to the query rotation based on changes to farm topology". Are there other logs I could be looking at?

Comment: Just for information used syntax: stsadm.exe -o adduser -url http://spbank/depa
rtment/PTSB/Open24TeamSite/ -userlogin omega\lidc825 -useremail aoife.obrien@per
manenttsb.ie -role reader -username "O'Brien, Aoife" -siteadmin Have no idea why the GUI was causing problems.